# Add custom CSS file in the header for only one language

Tags: css, magento, magento-1.9

I want to add custom CSS file for the Arabic Language.

I found how to add a CSS file to the `local.xml` like this

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/custom_style.css</name></action>
```

But I want to specify it for one language only.

Any idea how to implement this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

In layout file you can use this code outside of default tag

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <STORE_arabic>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/custom_css.css</stylesheet>
            <params>media="screen"</params>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </STORE_arabic>
    <default>
       ...
    </default>
</layout>
```

'arabic' is your store code.

Answer (score 0):

If you can work out a means of how, just add your stylesheet in regardless of language / locality and add a class to the body tag.

```
<body class="arabic">
```

and add that selector to your new stylesheet.

Comment: This way,  I will have big CSS file and I don't think it's recommended